# emulator worked, now tries to load forever

Tags: android, emulation

When I first installed eclipse and the sdk, I could get helloworld to load in an emulator just fine.
Then I started using my phone directly, but now I need to use the emulator again.

I cant get helloworld to load on the emulator now.

Here's some data:

using: xp, avd manager in eclipse

```
CONSOLE:

[2011-03-17 15:02:44 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2011-03-17 15:02:44 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-03-17 15:02:44 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-03-17 15:02:44 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-03-17 15:02:44 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'my_avd' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2011-03-17 15:02:44 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2011-03-17 15:03:08 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-03-17 15:03:08 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

LOGCAT (just errors; this is after an hour and a half!):

```
ERROR/vold(27): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
ERROR/vold(27): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
ERROR/vold(27): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
ERROR/vold(27): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
ERROR/BatteryService(31): usbOnlinePath not found
ERROR/BatteryService(31): batteryVoltagePath not found BatteryService(31): batteryTemperaturePath not found 
ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(31): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
ERROR/dalvikvm(31): HeapWorker is wedged: 11070ms spent inside Lcom/android/internal/os/BinderInternal$GcWatcher;.finalize()V
ERROR/dalvikvm(31): VM aborting
ERROR/BatteryService(77): usbOnlinePath not found
ERROR/BatteryService(77): batteryVoltagePath not found
ERROR/BatteryService(77): batteryTemperaturePath not found
ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(77): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
ERROR/dalvikvm(77): HeapWorker is wedged: 11064ms spent inside Lcom/android/internal/os/BinderInternal$GcWatcher;.finalize()V
ERROR/BatteryService(100): usbOnlinePath not found 
ERROR/BatteryService(100): batteryVoltagePath not found 
ERROR/BatteryService(100): batteryTemperaturePath not found
ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(100): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
ERROR/dalvikvm(100): HeapWorker is wedged: 11225ms spent inside Lcom/android/internal/os/BinderInternal$GcWatcher;.finalize()V
ERROR/dalvikvm(100): VM aborting
ERROR/installd(33): eof
ERROR/installd(33): failed to read size
ERROR/BatteryService(123): usbOnlinePath not found
ERROR/BatteryService(123): batteryVoltagePath not found
ERROR/BatteryService(123): batteryTemperaturePath not found
ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(123): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
ERROR/dalvikvm(123): HeapWorker is wedged: 10990ms spent inside Lcom/android/internal/os/BinderInternal$GcWatcher;.finalize()V
```

It never gets passed "HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME" in the console.
Notice how it seems to get stuck in "vm aborted" loop.

Im stumped, and ready to reinstall the sdk entirely.
Any suggestions before I have to do that? Greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is pretty obvious, but have you tried restarting Eclipse?

Comment: That's too bad. I've had to reinstall it myself this week, it might be faster to reinstall it now rather than wait for a solution.

Comment: I think so too. Fortunately, I got everything backedup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't rush to reinstall the SDK. Try creating a new AVD with the same API level that your original one had and run your app on that one. If that's OK just delete the original one as its image may be corrupted. You won't lose anything and it's not worth spending time on trying to fix it.

Comment: Oh that's a shame. If you do reinstall the SDK with SDK Tools R10, I should warn you that the emulator is really slow now. I wish I'd stayed with 2.3.3